# Displaying a tree of content in textboxes in HTML/JS/JQueryUI

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I am working on a program to manipulate a tree of content. Please see below:

```
Parent1
    Child1
    Child2
Parent2
    Child3
Parent3
    Child4
```

I want to display this on a JQueryUI based page, where the user can graphically manipulate this tree by dragging and dropping a "Child" to another Parent. For example, if user may drag "Child2" to "Parent3", in which case Child2 will now appear under Parent3 - indented as shown. Also, the user may add a new Child5 and specify an associated Parent, etc. So, new entities may be added dynamically to the list (with the proper indenting as appropriate).

What's the best components to use for this guys? I tried something like the following below, but it has a few issues. The textinput is a fixed width and doesn't wrap just to the size of the text, if you click on the textinput the blinking cursor is present (I just want it to be output text), and the draggable is not working for some reason.

HTML:

```
<div id="container" class="ui-widget-content">
<h3 class="ui-widget-header">Containment</h3>
<span id="draggable">  
    <input type="text" id="parent1" class="ui-state-active" value="Parent1" readonly>
    <br>
    <input type="text" id="child1" class="ui-state-active" value="Child1" readonly>
</span>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$(function() {
     $( "#parent1" ).draggable({containment: "#container"});
     $( "#child1" ).draggable({containment: "#container"});
});
```

I also want the large container box to be a fixed size and not dependent on the length of the list in the container box. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `<ul> or <li>`. This is basic HTML.
In the `<li>` You can place whatever you want. Such as a link or a input. Try it out!
You can find an example here: http://jsfiddle.net/2q9towgz/

Comment: Thanks man. But one thing I do want is for each such list entry to have it's own individual effect. So, each parent/child will have it's own rectangular border (fitted to length of text) and background color (within the rectangular box). Also, if it's a simple list, how can I drag and drop a child entry between parents?

Comment: I don't know Javascript, but if this worked for you can you please make it as the answer @Phoeniyx